# Looping nas rows de uma tabela em VB

Tags: banco-de-dados, visual-basic-6, microsoft-access

Estou tentando fazer esse looping entre as rows do banco de dados funcionar.
Tenho um código pronto em C# e estou usando como referência, mas não consigo fazer essa parte rodar.
 Aqui ficou mais ou menos assim:

```
    For Each Row In ds.Tables(0).Rows
        barcode.CodeToEncode = dr("productId")
        dr("Barcode") = barcode.generateBarcodeToByteArray()
    Next
```

Comment: Desculpa, VB6, essa é a minha primeira pergunta aqui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já consegui resolver o problema. O código ficou assim:

```
    For Each Row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
        barcode.CodeToEncode = Row("productId")
        Row("Barcode") = barcode.generateBarcodeToByteArray()
    Next
```

A confusão que eu tinha feito era com o "dr" no código em C# que estava:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
```

E eu não sabia que o dr era uma variável do tipo DataRow...